# ReSharper CLT and ReSpeller with NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

> My ultimate goal is to use ReSpeller Free with ReSharper Command Line Tools in my CI software. Any hint's toward figuring this out, outside of what i've already tried would be helpful.

**What I've tried**:

1. According to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html#using-extensions-with-inspectcode) there is a way to use extensions
   with ReSharper CLT. `InspectCode -it` shows that spell checking is
   an enabled featured via the latest ReSharper download link:
   https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html. But,
   when running the default output command `-o`, passing it my solution
   file, no output is generated related for spell checking and I *for
   sure* have spelling errors in my test file.
2. Using NuGet packages, I placed the `EtherealCode.ReSpeller` package into the project directory, but while it looks like it attempts to load none of the assemblies that `EtherealCode.ReSpeller` needs seem to load: [image: output from my run of <code>InspectCode /output="Test.xml" pathtosln.sln</code>]
3. Other solutions like some build in VisualStudio packages `Spell.Check` and `NetSpell` fail in comparison to ReSpeller, so although I've tried them, I am not really thrilled about using them.
4. I've checked the forums and came across this semi-helpful post https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-436208, but it's 2 year old and the support team doesn't seem to care to prioritize it.
5. This blog post using Cake to manually copy in DLLs for Typo Checking https://tpodolak.com/blog/2017/10/27/finding-typos-resharper-command-line-tools-respeller-cake/ is great, but it doens't use the currently supported nuget package system that ReSharper [says they are using](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html#using-extensions-with-inspectcode).

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?